# Scala type class dictionaries?

Tags: scala

In [this paper](http://ropas.snu.ac.kr/~bruno/papers/TypeClasses.pdf), they give an example of a Scala class:

```
class S[A](l : String, formatD: Format[A]) extends Format[A] {
  def format(s : String) = formatD.format(s+l)
}
```

and say:

> An important difference is that,
>   with type classes, we cannot implement a corresponding
>   instance for the `S[A]` model.
>   The problem is that, to define `S`, a `String` argument is required but
>   type class instances can only take type class dictionaries in the
>   instance constraints.
>   Thus, the following is not allowed:
>
> ```hs
> instance (String, Format a) ⇒ Format a where ...
> ```

What are they referring to when they say "type class dictionaries"?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to provide more context? I don't think you've posted enough for others to be able to answer this. For example, the code you've posted, by itself, has nothing to do with type classes, and `Format` is not a type in the standard library. In particular, I think if you would post what type class the author is attempting to construct, someone might be able to answer you.

Comment: Ok, you seem to be referring to [this paper](http://ropas.snu.ac.kr/~bruno/papers/TypeClasses.pdf).

Comment: Yes, that's the paper I'm reading.  And no, it's not a type class.  The section I quoted was explaining why this particular class couldn't be a type class.

Comment: The short, partial answer is: They're not talking about "Scala type class dictionaries", they're talking about Haskell, as can be seen in the sentence and code right after the one you originally quoted. (I edited into your question.) As I understand it, they're comparing Scala and Haskell approaches to solving the same problem, and giving an example of something that Scala can do, but Haskell can't. I don't know enough Haskell to explain why, or what those type class dictionaries are in Haskell. Maybe if you edit the [haskell] tag into your question, someone who knows Haskell can help you?

Comment: I think I can piece together a working understanding now.  Thanks, Dan!

Comment: Could you please answer your own question in this case? It might be useful to others.